# Syncing local and remote website files with FileZilla (kind of like Dropbox)

Tags: sync, ftp, dropbox

just making my first website and I've been using FileZilla for a week now. Was wondering if anyone could tell me how to make FileZilla auto sync my all my files at a push of a button. The only way I know is deleting/uploading the whole thing again. Dropbox is the best description I can give.